# Можно ли программно отключить каждую вторую вертикаль пикселей?

Tags: железо, поиск-программ, ноутбук, монитор

Проблема с монитором на ноуте. Каждая вторая вертикаль отображает красные пиксели. Ищу способ решить проблему.

Comment: думаю это больше аппаратная часть нежели программная.